# Embed VBScript inside Windows batch file

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

Is it possible to embed VBScript within a batch file?

I currently have a .CMD file that calls a .VBS file using

```
cscript //NoLogo MyScript.vbs
```

but I'd prefer to distribute just a single .CMD file.

---

**EDIT**: There is a similar question with answers on how to do this without generating an intermediate file at all: [Is it possible to embed and execute VBScript within a batch file without using a temporary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074476)

Comment: Found an interesting hack where a batch script scans itself for labels (which are the VBScript) and writes it out to a new VBS file, which it executes http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=103686.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to embed and execute VBScript within a batch file without using a temporary file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074476/is-it-possible-to-embed-and-execute-vbscript-within-a-batch-file-without-using-a)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=103686.0

```
@echo off
echo This is batch
:wscript.echo "This VBScript"
:wscript.echo "Today is " & day(date) & "-" & month(date) & "-" & year(date)
findstr "^:" "%~sf0">temp.vbs & cscript //nologo temp.vbs & del temp.vbs
echo This is batch again
```