# How to close last tab in firefox using windows command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am creating a batch file to handle firefox tabs.
I want to close the last tab in firefox using windows command.

I have tried this command using title name

```
taskkill /IM firefox.exe /FI "WindowTitle eq localhost*"
```

It closes all the window

I have searched in windows command, there are no direct way.
Is there any possibilities ?

Comment: @Christian.K I have edited my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to use VBScript code to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> keys to Firefox.

Save this code as `closeActiveTab.vbs` and run it with `cscript closeActiveTab.vbs` in your batch file or [embed the code inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037709/embed-vbscript-inside-windows-batch-file).

```vbs
Dim Shell, WMI, query, process

Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
query = "SELECT ProcessId FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'firefox.exe'"

For Each process In WMI.ExecQuery(query)
    Shell.AppActivate process.ProcessId
    WScript.Sleep 100
    Shell.SendKeys "^w"
Next
```

Based on [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/727792/409372).

Comment: To close only the last tab open in the for loop you have to exit immediately.
thank you very much for the solution