# How can open and close link in Firefox?

Tags: c#, firefox

i need to open some links in firefox or chrome and after download is finished close any of them 
i can open link with this command :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("firefox.exe", "http://www.example.com?bookid=1");
```

I have Firefox set to one-window mode it opens a tab. This tab is killed (but not the main window) when I issue the Kill() method
and i can close opened tab with this command :

```
var proc = Process.Start("firefox.exe", "http://www.example.com");
proc.Kill();
```

but how can close specified tab with indicate with url ?

Comment: my process.Start doesnt take parameters - does this code compile?

Comment: Then get a new one ;) @BugFinder. It is there, really. http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Diagnostics.Process.Start);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

Comment: Hmm, ok - I may not have all the right usings up then

Comment: refer this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/32776912/4988990

Comment: Ugly, but it might work @DarshanPatel

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not a real answer to your question, but you don't need a browser to download a file, you can do that from C# directly.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com"), @"C:\temp\stackoverflow.html");
```

I don't think it is possible to close a specific tab in FireFox, I don't think there are any APIs to help you with that. If you are looking for a controllable browser, you might want to look into [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp).